# jQuery.Deferred with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple list to test out jQuery Deferred with setTimeout.

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

On my script, I created a simple function. The idea behind is that for every LI, it will replace the content at certain interval and when everything is completed, it will print 'all done' message.

```
function listing() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var promises = [];
    var promise;
    var index = 0;
    var list = $('ul').find('li');
    list.each(function(index) {
        var that = $(this);
        promise = $.Deferred();
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function() {
                that.html(i);
                promise.resolve();
                promises.push(promise);
            }, 8000*index);
        })(index);

    });

    $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

$.when(listing().done(function() {
    console.log('all done');
}));
```

Intended result is to have the content of the LI to be replaced every 8 seconds and once it's all replace, it will wait for 2 seconds before it prints 'all done'.

Currently, it will print 'all done' after 2 seconds and will replace LIs after 8 seconds.

I am new with jQuery Deferred, any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not pushing anything to the promises array in the each loop

```
function listing() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var promises = [];
    var promise;
    var index = 0;
    var list = $('ul').find('li');
    list.each(function (index) {
        var that = $(this);
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.html(index);
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 8000);
        //push the deferred outside the timeout
        promises.push(deferred.promise());
    });

    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

$.when(listing().done(function () {
    console.log('all done');
}));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TQajk/)

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems like the 'all done' message get printed out right away?

Comment: @user3427578 if it inside the timeout.. the promises are not added to the array until the time out callback is executed... so when `$.when` is executed the `promises` array is empty